# Wrong openzeppelin dependencies

Tags: hardhat, openzeppelin, npm

In my hardhat project I'm using [openzeppelin-contracts-upgradeable](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts-upgradeable).
I have installed the latest version using the command `npm i @openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable` which brings the latest version for now - `4.7.3`.

Going over [contract ERC721Upgradeable in github](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts-upgradeable/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721Upgradeable.sol) I see in line 347:

```
    delete _tokenApprovals[tokenId];
```

While in my local node_modules I see a different code (older version):

[image]

I removed openzeppelin folder from my node_modules, cleared npm-cache and re-installed it using command `npm i @openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable`. I can see in the `package.json` file that the installed version is the right version (4.7.3) but still it differs from [the one I see in github](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts-upgradeable).

How could this be? How can I make sure I'm s latest version?

On the left is my local version (4.7.3 according to the package.json file) on the right the version in github (also version 4.7.3):

[image]

Comment: You might get a faster answer on the openzeppelin forum